# make aspx page display sml document

Tags: asp.net, xml

Im trying to make an aspx page display as xml for an rss feed

the output looks like its formed ok when i view the source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?><rss version="2.0"><channel><title>phil</title><link>http://www.mysite.co.uk/blog.aspx</link><description>phils blog</description><item><title>Test Blog</title><link>

        http://www.phil.co.uk/blog/test-blog.aspx</link><description>test description</description><pubDate>2011-10-21T14:19:28</pubDate><guid>      http://www.phil.co.uk/blog/test-blog.aspx</guid></item></channel></rss>
```

But when i view the page in chrome it just shows the text from the nodes and not a visual of the xml structure. What do i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Google [Chrome Tree Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbammbheopgpmaagmckhpjbfgdfkpadb?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to Use EXtensible Stylesheet Language (XSTL)

You can display xml directly on browser without using any ASPX page. It is used to styling of your xml.

Let me know, if you have any concern.